# non sequentially compact space of sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, compactness

given $d(x,y)= \sum{2^{-i}\frac{|x_i-y_i|}{1+|x_i-y_i|}}$ metric on the space of sequences.

disproof: the Set M={$x \in l | d(0,x)=1  $ } of all sequences with d(0,x)=1 is a sequentially compact space.

I am not sure if I'm mistaken, but M, since it is closed and bounded, is compact. Now to disproof the sequentially comapact property, I have to show every sequence of sequences in M has an convergent subsequence.

How can I construct sequences that fulfill actually d(0,x)=1?
I thougt 
$k_i=(i^{-1},i^{-1},i^{-1},...,i^{-1},0,0,0,...)$ 
since lim $k_i$=0.
But unfortunally none of these have the desired property.

Thank you.

Greetings.

Comment: Be careful : "closed + bounded implies compact" is a theorem that is valid in $\mathbb{R}^n$ only. It is not true in general. For arbitrary metric spaces the theorem reads: "A subset of a metric space is compact if and only if it is complete and totally bounded."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $d(x,y)= \sum{2^{-i}\frac{|x_i-y_i|}{1+|x_i-y_i|}}$

If the enumeration of indices $i$ starts from $1$, then $d(x,0)<1$ for each sequence $x$, so $M$ is empty. Thus I’ll assume that it starts from $0$.
For $n>1$ put $k_n=(n+1,2/n,0,0,\dots)$. Then the sequence  $\{k_n\}$ belongs to $M$ and clearly diverges.